# Reset the counter value of an auto-number column in access using SQL request without delete relation ships?

Tags: sql, delphi

After a many searches in Google I found this request to reset counter. But when trying this  message appear:

> you can't change counter because column is a part of many relation ships

The request is:

```
ALTER TABLE client ALTER COLUMN id COUNTER(1, 1)
```

So I need to reset all columns with auto-number without removing relationships with a SQL request.

Thank you.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Resetting the counter sounds like a really bad idea... unless this is a test database.

Comment: If the DB itself says you can't alter the counter, then you can't alter the counter. You will have to drop the relationships that are preventing the alteration, then do the alteration, then restore the relationships. There is really nothing else you can do about it.